# Multiple counts in one SQL query with grouping

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I want to run a query to get a count of open incident and closed incidents grouped by year and month, the below query works fine without the grouping, but once I add the group it will not work!

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Opened FROM Incidents) AS Total 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Solved FROM Incidents WHERE (MONTH(Closedate)=MONTH(Opendate))) AS Solved
GROUP BY YEAR(Incidents.Opendate)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use single a SELECT statement with CASE expression

```
SELECT YEAR(Incidents.Opendate) AS [Year], 
       MONTH(Incidents.Opendate) AS [Month], 
       COUNT(*) AS Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Closedate) = MONTH(Opendate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Solved
FROM Incidents
GROUP BY YEAR(Incidents.Opendate), MONTH(Incidents.Opendate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Incidents) as Total ,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM Incidents WHERE (Month(Closedate)=MONTH(Opendate))) as Solved
    FROM Incidents
    Group by YEAR(Incidents.Opendate)
```

Comment: Shree, the query above did not worked. I got this error (Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it, below is the query

```
select  COUNT(CASE WHEN Month(Closedate)=Month(Opendate) then 1 else null end) AS closed,COUNT(*) AS Opened
from incidents
Group by Year(Opendate), Month(Opendate)
Order by Year(Opendate), Month(Opendate)
```

Comment: You can probably omit the `else null` bit. I think most SQL products allow that, defaulting the missing `ELSE` clause to `ELSE NULL`. However, isn't this essentially same as @Alexander Fedorenko's answer?